# PhpStorm not recognizing TYPO3 Fluid closing tags

Tags: typo3, phpstorm, fluid

I have a Fluid template where I break a list into groups of 4, like:

```
<ul>
<f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="i">
    <li>(CONTENT HERE)</li>
    <f:if condition="{i.cycle} % 4">
</ul>
<ul>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
</ul>
```

I've added the Fluid XML namespaces into my project [like this](https://buzz.typo3.org/teams/extbase/article/howto-autocompletion-for-fluid-in-phpstorm/), but PhpStorm still informs me that my closing `</f:if>` tag 'matches nothing'.

Is there a way to configure PhpStorm to recognize this construct?

Am I violating best practices by wrapping a closing and opening tag in an `<f:if>`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fluid.. so just a thought: *maybe* it's because you have `</ul><ul>` before the `</f:if>`. The XML/HTML parser may think that `<f:if` is already closed before `</ul>` (especially if it's a HTML5) hence `matches nothing`. IF that's the case, then possible workaround would be to print those `ul` pair using actual Fluid syntax (does Fluid has some sort of echo/print tag/instruction? You could assign such text to a variable and then output it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first thing that PHP Storm validates is proper nesting of XML/HTML - like tags and in your sample you break it mercilessly (from point of view the IDE, not mine as I understand the need of use the modulo *break* in the Fluid) and it doesn't matter if you'll add valid XML namespaces or even disable XML inspector at all.

What's more it's so *clever* that is able to recognize tags even in inline *then* notification (damn it!), this will also display IDE level error:

```html
<ul>
    <f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="i">
        <li>Item {i.cycle}</li>
        {f:if(condition: '{i.cycle} % 4', then: '</ul><ul>')}
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

The only solution that I found till now and using it with success in many projects is custom ViewHelper in custom ext (for IDE it's important that you declare `startTage` before `endTag`!):

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Myext\ViewHelpers;
/**
 * {namespace myNs=Vendor\Myext\ViewHelpers}
 *
 * = Inline samples
 *
 * === Break the list:
 * {myNs:breakTagByModulo(iterator: i, modulo: 2)}
 * or...
 * {myNs:breakTagByModulo(iterator: i, modulo: 2, startTag: '<ul class="next-level">', endTag: '</ul>')}
 *
 *  result on valid modulo:
 *  </ul><ul class="next-level">
 *
 * === Break the Bootstrap row:
 * {myNs:breakTagByModulo(iterator: i, modulo: 2, startTag: '<div class="row">', endTag: '</div>')}
 * 
 *  result on valid modulo:
 *  </div><div class="row">
 *  
 * etc...
 */
class BreakTagByModuloViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * @param array   $iterator Iterator from `f:for` VH
     * @param integer $modulo   Modulo to check
     * @param boolean $skipLast If skipLast==true VH will return false even if condition is correct, needed for `not full` lists
     * @param string  $startTag Begin of the tag
     * @param string  $endTag   End of the tag
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function render($iterator, $modulo, $skipLast = true, $startTag = '<ul>', $endTag = '</ul>') {
        $i = $iterator['cycle'];
        $bool = ($i % $modulo == 0);
        if ($skipLast && $iterator['isLast']) {
            $bool = false;
        }

        return ($bool) ? $endTag . $startTag : null;
    }
}

?>
```

The usage in the view is showed above, just for your sample it will be something like:

```html
{namespace myNs=Vendor\Myext\ViewHelpers}

<ul>
    <f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="i">
        <li>(CONTENT HERE)</li>
        {myNs:breakTagByModulo(iterator: i, modulo: 4)}
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

*(of course you're replacing `myNs`, `Vendor` and `Myext` with your own values)*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach to ensure a solid html structure. Mixing template HTML with HTML coming from view helpers seems like a dangerous idea, when the opening tag comes from one and the closing tag the other.

Since splitting the list into chunks seems to be a logical necessity rather than a presentational, the logic for this should happen in a controller rather than the view. If for some reason, you can't change the controller logic (3rd party extension?), you should resort to a widget / view helper. In there you could split the list into sets of 4 using pure PHP and then use a  loop to iterate the sets in your template. This way the HTML will be less breakable, easier to maintain and easier to understand (for you and for PHPSTORM).

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by LazyOne's comment, and Biesior's answer. Taking the following:

```
<ul>
    <f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="i">
        <li>Item {i.cycle}</li>
        {f:if(condition: '{i.cycle} % 4', else: '</ul><ul>')}
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

I tried replacing the angle brackets with HTML entities, and Unicode escape sequences, both of which where output in full. Then I thought to do character replacement. I found the [v:format.replace](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Format/ReplaceViewHelper.html) viewhelper, and I did the following:

```
<v:format.replace substring="(" replacement="<"><v:format.replace substring=")" replacement=">">{f:if(condition: '{iter.cycle} % 4', else: '(/ul)(ul)')}</v:format.replace></v:format.replace>
```

That is, I put parentheses in my code, and switched them to angle brackets for the output.

So there's a ridiculously verbose option for anyone who feels like using it.